# Replacing $ for jQuery - .addClass method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue trying to fix a conflict between both libraries and have used the `noConflict` in some sections, however I keep getting the *$active is null* error

I'm specialized in server-side scripting and not in Javascript (nor have time to read some documentation) so would appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

First (I'm just guessing here) jQuery adds a class which will be used later

```
jQuery(".paging a:first").addClass("active");
```

Now, it's time to use that class

```
var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
```

Since the code is for a slider the error appears every time this line is reached so my question is... Is there any way I can remove the `$` and still use jQuery in that line?

P.S: I'm using jQuery 1.6.1 min and MooTools 1.2 although I doubt this is relevant I know they have conflicts so probably the source of this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select an element by it's class in jQuery you need to use CSS style notation in a jQuery object, which in your example would be `jQuery(".active")`. Try this:

```
var triggerID = jQuery(".active").attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
```

To use your original code, you'd need to assign the `$active` variable to be the jQuery object containing the element, like this:

```
var $active = jQuery(".paging a:first").addClass("active");
var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; // This will now work, assuming it's in the same scope as the above.
```

Answer (score 1):

$active has nothing to do with jQuery in this case (though it might be a jQuery variable). In javascript you can name variables "$something" without a problem, and it doesn't collide with something named simply "$", which is another variable-name altogether. It's like saying you have removed all references to the variable "car", but don't understand why you get an error complaining about the lack of a "carpet". They're totally independent, thus the code you have posted is insufficient to see what is wrong.

**[Edit]**
If this sounded harsh in some way it's just me having a problem formulating myself in an understanding way on this matter, as I was simply trying to educate, not implying that this is something that you should know. It's an error a lot of peoples do in javascript (at least several I know of).

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of replacing `$` with `jQuery` wherever you would normally use `$`.

So, instead of the typical:

`$('.active').attr('rel')`

use:

`jQuery('.active').attr('rel')`

Answer (score 0):

`$active` is a javascript variable (they chose to put the `$` in front of it to help them remember it stores a jQuery object, but the behavior is the same).

So, replacing every instance of `$active` by `active` should still work. I don't know ifit will solve your problem though.

One other thing you should try is putting your code in a closure:

```
(function($){
    // your code
})(jQuery);
```

That way, inside of the closure, `$` will only reference jQuery

Comment: I already tried this however I needed to fix 2 lines containing `$active`. Also replacing with `active` didn't fix it. Thanks